# Contract deploys and gets funded but gives 'Gas estimation failed' error later on

Tags: chainlink, insurance

I am updating a parametric insurance smart contract written last year and have run into a problem. I am able to successfully deploy the insurance provider contract (the parent contract) and fund it with LINK. However, when I try to create the insurance contract itself (the daughter contracts), I get a 'gas estimation failed' error. The parent contract is funded with Link so I don't get what the issue might be.

Link to parent contract on Etherscan:  https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x2d37bb3cf0A1E7C309b3B073E9B7721c8956F187

When I decompile the deployed parent contract on Etherscan I see an error trace starting with the following:
I failed with these:

- getContractBalance()
- _fallback()
  All the rest is below.

The error I keep getting whenever I try to deploy the daughter contract is the 'gas estimaion failed' error.

The smart contract itself is pasted below. Is anyone able to help me figure out where the problem is and how to solve it? None of the similar gas-estimation-error questions here had an answer that worked for me. Any help is appreciated.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

//Brownie Imports
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/Ownable.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorInterface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";



contract InsuranceProvider {

    using SafeMathChainlink for uint;
    address payable public insurer = msg.sender;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    uint public constant DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60; //How many seconds in a day. 60 for testing, 86400 for Production

    uint256 constant private ORACLE_PAYMENT = 0.1 * 10**18; // 0.1 LINK
    address public constant LINK_KOVAN = 0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088 ; //address of LINK token on Kovan

    //here is where all the insurance contracts are stored.
    mapping (address => InsuranceContract) contracts;


    constructor()   public payable {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Prevents a function being run unless it's called by the Insurance Provider
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(insurer == msg.sender,'Only Insurance provider can do this');
        _;
    }


   /**
    * @dev Event to log when a contract is created
    */
    event contractCreated(address _insuranceContract, uint _premium, uint _totalCover);


    /**
     * @dev Create a new contract for client, automatically approved and deployed to the blockchain
     */
    function newContract(address payable _client, uint _duration, uint _premium, uint _payoutValue, string memory _cropLocation) public payable onlyOwner() returns(address) {


        //create contract, send payout amount so contract is fully funded plus a small buffer
        InsuranceContract i = (new InsuranceContract){value:(_payoutValue * 1 ether).div(uint(getLatestPrice()))}(_client, _duration, _premium, _payoutValue, _cropLocation, LINK_KOVAN,ORACLE_PAYMENT);
        
        contracts[address(i)] = i;  //store insurance contract in contracts Map

        //emit an event to say the contract has been created and funded
        emit contractCreated(address(i), msg.value, _payoutValue);

        //now that contract has been created, we need to fund it with enough LINK tokens to fulfil 1 Oracle request per day, with a small buffer added
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(i.getChainlinkToken());
        link.transfer(address(i), ((_duration.div(DAY_IN_SECONDS)) + 2) * ORACLE_PAYMENT.mul(2));


        return address(i);

    }


    /**
     * @dev returns the contract for a given address
     */
    function getContract(address _contract) external view returns (InsuranceContract) {
        return contracts[_contract];
    }

    /**
     * @dev updates the contract for a given address
     */
    function updateContract(address payable _contract) external {
        InsuranceContract i = InsuranceContract(_contract);
        i.updateContract();
    }

    /**
     * @dev gets the current rainfall for a given contract address
     */
    function getContractRainfall(address payable _contract) external view returns(uint) {
        InsuranceContract i = InsuranceContract(_contract);
        return i.getCurrentRainfall();
    }

    /**
     * @dev gets the data request count for a given contract address
     */
    function getContractRequestCount(address payable _contract) external view returns(uint) {
        InsuranceContract i = InsuranceContract(_contract);
        return i.getRequestCount();
    }



    /**
     * @dev Get the insurer address for this insurance provider
     */
    function getInsurer() external view returns (address) {
        return insurer;
    }



    /**
     * @dev Get the status of a given Contract
     */
    function getContractStatus(address payable _address) external view returns (bool) {
        InsuranceContract i = InsuranceContract(_address);
        return i.getContractStatus();
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return how much ether is in this master contract
     */
    function getContractBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Function to end provider contract, in case of bugs or needing to update logic etc, funds are returned to insurance provider, including any remaining LINK tokens
     */
    function endContractProvider() external payable onlyOwner() {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(LINK_KOVAN);
        require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
        selfdestruct(insurer);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID,
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // If the round is not complete yet, timestamp is 0
        require(timeStamp > 0, "Round not complete");
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * @dev fallback function, to receive ether
     */
    receive() external payable {  }
    fallback() external payable {  }
    

}

contract InsuranceContract is ChainlinkClient, Ownable  {

    using SafeMathChainlink for uint;
    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    uint public constant DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60; //How many seconds in a day. 60 for testing, 86400 for Production
    uint public constant DROUGHT_DAYS_THRESDHOLD = 3 ;  //Number of consecutive days without rainfall to be defined as a drought
    uint256 private oraclePaymentAmount;

    address payable public insurer;   //
    address payable client;           //
    uint startDate;
    uint duration;
    uint premium;
    uint payoutValue;
    string cropLocation;


    uint256[2] public currentRainfallList;
    bytes32[2] public jobIds;
    address[2] public oracles;

    string constant WORLD_WEATHER_ONLINE_URL = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/weather.ashx?";
    string constant WORLD_WEATHER_ONLINE_KEY = "629c6dd09bbc4364b7a33810200911";
    string constant WORLD_WEATHER_ONLINE_PATH = "data.current_condition.0.precipMM";

    string constant OPEN_WEATHER_URL = "https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?";
    string constant OPEN_WEATHER_KEY = "b4e40205aeb3f27b74333393de24ca79";
    string constant OPEN_WEATHER_PATH = "rain.1h";

    string constant WEATHERBIT_URL = "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current?";
    string constant WEATHERBIT_KEY = "5e05aef07410401fac491b06eb9e8fc8";
    string constant WEATHERBIT_PATH = "data.0.precip";

    uint daysWithoutRain;                   //how many days there has been with 0 rain
    bool contractActive;                    //is the contract currently active, or has it ended
    bool contractPaid = false;
    uint currentRainfall = 0;               //what is the current rainfall for the location
    uint currentRainfallDateChecked = now;  //when the last rainfall check was performed
    uint requestCount = 0;                  //how many requests for rainfall data have been made so far for this insurance contract
    uint dataRequestsSent = 0;             //variable used to determine if both requests have been sent or not


    /**
     * @dev Prevents a function being run unless it's called by Insurance Provider
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() override {
        require(insurer == msg.sender,'Only Insurance provider can do this');
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Prevents a function being run unless the Insurance Contract duration has been reached
     */
    modifier onContractEnded() {
        if (startDate + duration < now) {
          _;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Prevents a function being run unless contract is still active
     */
    modifier onContractActive() {
        require(contractActive == true ,'Contract has ended, cant interact with it anymore');
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Prevents a data request to be called unless it's been a day since the last call (to avoid spamming and spoofing results)
     * apply a tolerance of 2/24 of a day or 2 hours.
     */
    modifier callFrequencyOncePerDay() {
        require(now.sub(currentRainfallDateChecked) > (DAY_IN_SECONDS.sub(DAY_IN_SECONDS.div(12))),'Can only check rainfall once per day');
        _;
    }

    event contractCreated(address _insurer, address _client, uint _duration, uint _premium, uint _totalCover);
    event contractPaidOut(uint _paidTime, uint _totalPaid, uint _finalRainfall);
    event contractEnded(uint _endTime, uint _totalReturned);
    event ranfallThresholdReset(uint _rainfall);
    event dataRequestSent(bytes32 requestId);
    event dataReceived(uint _rainfall);

    /**
     * @dev Creates a new Insurance contract
     */
    constructor(address payable _client, uint _duration, uint _premium, uint _payoutValue, string memory _cropLocation,
                address _link, uint256 _oraclePaymentAmount)  payable Ownable() public {

        //set ETH/USD Price Feed
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);

        //initialize variables required for Chainlink Network interaction
        setChainlinkToken(_link);
        oraclePaymentAmount = _oraclePaymentAmount;

        //first ensure insurer has fully funded the contract
        require(msg.value >= _payoutValue.div(uint(getLatestPrice())), "Not enough funds sent to contract");

        //now initialize values for the contract
        insurer= msg.sender;
        client = _client;
        startDate = now ; //contract will be effective immediately on creation
        duration = _duration;
        premium = _premium;
        payoutValue = _payoutValue;
        daysWithoutRain = 0;
        contractActive = true;
        cropLocation = _cropLocation;

        //set the oracles and jodids to values from nodes on market.link
        //oracles[0] = 0x240bae5a27233fd3ac5440b5a598467725f7d1cd;
        //oracles[1] = 0x5b4247e58fe5a54a116e4a3be32b31be7030c8a3;
        //jobIds[0] = '1bc4f827ff5942eaaa7540b7dd1e20b9';
        //jobIds[1] = 'e67ddf1f394d44e79a9a2132efd00050';

        //or if you have your own node and job setup you can use it for both requests
        oracles[0] = 0x05c8fadf1798437c143683e665800d58a42b6e19;
        oracles[1] = 0x05c8fadf1798437c143683e665800d58a42b6e19;
        jobIds[0] = 'a17e8fbf4cbf46eeb79e04b3eb864a4e';
        jobIds[1] = 'a17e8fbf4cbf46eeb79e04b3eb864a4e';

        emit contractCreated(insurer,
                             client,
                             duration,
                             premium,
                             payoutValue);
    }

   /**
     * @dev Calls out to an Oracle to obtain weather data
     */
    function updateContract() public onContractActive() returns (bytes32 requestId)   {
        //first call end contract in case of insurance contract duration expiring, if it hasn't then this function execution will resume
        checkEndContract();

        //contract may have been marked inactive above, only do request if needed
        if (contractActive) {
            dataRequestsSent = 0;
            //First build up a request to World Weather Online to get the current rainfall
            string memory url = string(abi.encodePacked(WORLD_WEATHER_ONLINE_URL, "key=",WORLD_WEATHER_ONLINE_KEY,"&q=",cropLocation,"&format=json&num_of_days=1"));
            checkRainfall(oracles[0], jobIds[0], url, WORLD_WEATHER_ONLINE_PATH);


            // Now build up the second request to WeatherBit
            url = string(abi.encodePacked(WEATHERBIT_URL, "city=",cropLocation,"&key=",WEATHERBIT_KEY));
            checkRainfall(oracles[1], jobIds[1], url, WEATHERBIT_PATH);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @dev Calls out to an Oracle to obtain weather data
     */
    function checkRainfall(address _oracle, bytes32 _jobId, string memory _url, string memory _path) private onContractActive() returns (bytes32 requestId)   {

        //First build up a request to get the current rainfall
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(_jobId, address(this), this.checkRainfallCallBack.selector);

        req.add("get", _url); //sends the GET request to the oracle
        req.add("path", _path);
        req.addInt("times", 100);

        requestId = sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, oraclePaymentAmount);

        emit dataRequestSent(requestId);
    }


    /**
     * @dev Callback function - This gets called by the Oracle Contract when the Oracle Node passes data back to the Oracle Contract
     * The function will take the rainfall given by the Oracle and updated the Inusrance Contract state
     */
    function checkRainfallCallBack(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _rainfall) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) onContractActive() callFrequencyOncePerDay()  {
        //set current temperature to value returned from Oracle, and store date this was retrieved (to avoid spam and gaming the contract)
       currentRainfallList[dataRequestsSent] = _rainfall;
       dataRequestsSent = dataRequestsSent + 1;

       //set current rainfall to average of both values
       if (dataRequestsSent > 1) {
          currentRainfall = (currentRainfallList[0].add(currentRainfallList[1]).div(2));
          currentRainfallDateChecked = now;
          requestCount +=1;

          //check if payout conditions have been met, if so call payoutcontract, which should also end/kill contract at the end
          if (currentRainfall == 0 ) { //temp threshold has been  met, add a day of over threshold
              daysWithoutRain += 1;
          } else {
              //there was rain today, so reset daysWithoutRain parameter
              daysWithoutRain = 0;
              emit ranfallThresholdReset(currentRainfall);
          }

          if (daysWithoutRain >= DROUGHT_DAYS_THRESDHOLD) {  // day threshold has been met
              //need to pay client out insurance amount
              payOutContract();
          }
       }

       emit dataReceived(_rainfall);

    }


    /**
     * @dev Insurance conditions have been met, do payout of total cover amount to client
     */
    function payOutContract() private onContractActive()  {

        //Transfer agreed amount to client
        client.transfer(address(this).balance);

        //Transfer any remaining funds (premium) back to Insurer
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(link.transfer(insurer, link.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");

        emit contractPaidOut(now, payoutValue, currentRainfall);

        //now that amount has been transferred, can end the contract
        //mark contract as ended, so no future calls can be done
        contractActive = false;
        contractPaid = true;

    }

    /**
     * @dev Insurance conditions have not been met, and contract expired, end contract and return funds
     */
    function checkEndContract() private onContractEnded()   {
        //Insurer needs to have performed at least 1 weather call per day to be eligible to retrieve funds back.
        //We will allow for 1 missed weather call to account for unexpected issues on a given day.
        if (requestCount >= (duration.div(DAY_IN_SECONDS) - 2)) {
            //return funds back to insurance provider then end/kill the contract
            insurer.transfer(address(this).balance);
        } else { //insurer hasn't done the minimum number of data requests, client is eligible to receive his premium back
            // need to use ETH/USD price feed to calculate ETH amount
            client.transfer(premium.div(uint(getLatestPrice())));
            insurer.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }

        //transfer any remaining LINK tokens back to the insurer
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(link.transfer(insurer, link.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer remaining LINK tokens");

        //mark contract as ended, so no future state changes can occur on the contract
        contractActive = false;
        emit contractEnded(now, address(this).balance);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID,
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // If the round is not complete yet, timestamp is 0
        require(timeStamp > 0, "Round not complete");
        return price;
    }


    /**
     * @dev Get the balance of the contract
     */
    function getContractBalance() external view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get the Crop Location
     */
    function getLocation() external view returns (string memory) {
        return cropLocation;
    }


    /**
     * @dev Get the Total Cover
     */
    function getPayoutValue() external view returns (uint) {
        return payoutValue;
    }


    /**
     * @dev Get the Premium paid
     */
    function getPremium() external view returns (uint) {
        return premium;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get the status of the contract
     */
    function getContractStatus() external view returns (bool) {
        return contractActive;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get whether the contract has been paid out or not
     */
    function getContractPaid() external view returns (bool) {
        return contractPaid;
    }


    /**
     * @dev Get the current recorded rainfall for the contract
     */
    function getCurrentRainfall() external view returns (uint) {
        return currentRainfall;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get the recorded number of days without rain
     */
    function getDaysWithoutRain() external view returns (uint) {
        return daysWithoutRain;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get the count of requests that has occured for the Insurance Contract
     */
    function getRequestCount() external view returns (uint) {
        return requestCount;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get the last time that the rainfall was checked for the contract
     */
    function getCurrentRainfallDateChecked() external view returns (uint) {
        return currentRainfallDateChecked;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get the contract duration
     */
    function getDuration() external view returns (uint) {
        return duration;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get the contract start date
     */
    function getContractStartDate() external view returns (uint) {
        return startDate;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get the current date/time according to the blockchain
     */
    function getNow() external view returns (uint) {
        return now;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Get address of the chainlink token
     */
    function getChainlinkToken() public view returns (address) {
        return chainlinkTokenAddress();
    }

    /**
     * @dev Helper function for converting a string to a bytes32 object
     */
    function stringToBytes32(string memory source) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
        if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
         return 0x0;
        }

        assembly { // solhint-disable-line no-inline-assembly
        result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }


    /**
     * @dev Helper function for converting uint to a string
     */
    function uint2str(uint _i) internal pure returns (string memory _uintAsString) {
        if (_i == 0) {
            return "0";
        }
        uint j = _i;
        uint len;
        while (j != 0) {
            len++;
            j /= 10;
        }
        bytes memory bstr = new bytes(len);
        uint k = len - 1;
        while (_i != 0) {
            bstr[k--] = byte(uint8(48 + _i % 10));
            _i /= 10;
        }
        return string(bstr);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Fallback function so contract function can receive ether when required
     */
    receive() external payable {  }
    fallback() external payable {  }
    


}
```

Comment: can you post a link to your deployed parent/factory contract on etherscan? Also what is the exact error? Gas estimation failed?

Comment: The etherscan link for the deployed parent contract:  https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x2d37bb3cf0A1E7C309b3B073E9B7721c8956F187
The exact error I am getting is:
Gas estimation failed: 'The execution failed due to an exception.'.

Comment: looks like maybe you're not sending enough ETH to the contract when you try to create the insurance contract/child contract. There is a require statement in the constructor of the generated contract that checks to see if it's been funded with enough ETH. If you comment it out and try again, see if it gets created.

If that is the issue, you need to work out what the difference is in the calculation of how much ETH is sent in the 'InsuranceContract i = (new InsuranceContract)' line in newContract, and the calculation to check the amount of ETH in the new contract constructor